# Unable to read data from transport connection

Tags: c#, thrift

I am using C++ Thrift server in Ubuntu and a C# Thrift Client on Windows for transmitting the file data using SSL. Data is flowing through for some time but after that I get an exception in the C# client:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond

But if I check on Ubuntu using netstat I still see the connection is alive.

Here is my code snippet on the client

```
Thrift.Transport.TSSLSocket socket = new TSSLSocket("192.168.0.227", 9092, 300, "cert.pem");
TBufferedTransport t = new TBufferedTransport(socket);
TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(t);
FileThriftAgent.Client fagent = new FileThriftAgent.Client(protocol);
t.Open();

try
{
    // reading data from a file and sending the data to the server
    ret = fagent.sendData(fname, data, datalen);
    if(!ret)
    {
        log.info("Data sending Failed");
    }
}                
catch (System.IO.IOException e)
{
    log.info("IO EXCEPTION:"+e);
}
```

On the c++ server side i am using a TThreadedServer

```
void Serve() {
    boost::shared_ptr<TSSLSocketFactory> sslSocketFactory(new SSLSocketFactory());
    sslSocketFactory->server(true);
    sslSocketFactory->ciphers("ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
    sslSocketFactory->loadCertificate("cert.pem");
    sslSocketFactory->loadPrivateKey("cert.pem");
    sslSocketFactory->authenticate(false);

    boost::shared_ptr<FileThriftAgentHandler> handler(this);
    boost::shared_ptr<TServerSocket> serverTransport(new      TSSLServerSocket(port, sslSocketFactory));
    TServerSocket(port));
    boost::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new    FileThriftAgentProcessor(handler));
    boost::shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
    boost::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

    TThreadedServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
    server.serve();
}
```

Comment: you should check your web.config settings for MaxReceiveTimeout and other imposed limits that might be there...

Comment: Hi icepickle, I don't have any web.config file in my project can you please tell me what values i can keep there.

Comment: @Icepickle: How does a `web.config` help with an **Ubuntu** C++ server and a C# **client**?

Comment: @Ram: Where I agree that it could  be a timeout issue. How much load is on that server? How many clients in parallel? Last not least how is the Thrift protocol/transport stack set up and what server type do you use (Simple, Threadpool, Nonblocking, ...)?

Comment: @JensG sorry, at first glance I had the impression that it is a timeout that gets forcibly closed by the .net socket. Such configuration values can normally be done in either the configuration settings or in the ClientConnectionFactory. However, I do not know the framework, and after surfing a bit on the https://thrift.apache.org/ website, I didn't actually get any wiser (though for java, they seem to have an interface for the IConnectionFactory, where I am sure, you could set up the limits for a timeout)

Comment: It could be handy to show your code, and to see if it is something in the line of: https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/csharp

Comment: @Icepickle: Added code in my post please have a look @ it

Comment: What about my questions? Too complicated? Overlooked?

Comment: @JensG: I am testing now with a single client connection, continuously sending 100k of data